# Putting ~ after id fetches record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

If we have an Active Record database say `Users`

User.find(`id`) works as expected:

[image: User.find(11)]

But so does User.find('`id~`')

[image: User.find('11~')]

Also User.find('`id~gibberish`')

[image: User.find('11~asdfasdf')]

**Is this a vulnerability or flaw of ActiveRecord?

How do I handle such requests appropriately?**

Comment: Please don't insert text as images.  Instead, please insert it appropriately formatted text.

Comment: @WayneConrad I presumed the exact response would be helpful. Will add it as text the next time a situation demands so.

Comment: For what it's worth, I personally think the screenshots are actually better in this particular scenario. Since the entire `User` object that's returned is a single line, if that text had been formatted as code, you'd have to do a *lot* of horizontal scrolling to see the whole thing. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help clear some things up, it is not `ActiveRecord`, it's Ruby's `to_i` method that you're seeing.

```
2.2.1 :001 > '11'.to_i
 => 11
2.2.1 :002 > '11~'.to_i
 => 11
2.2.1 :003 > '11~gibberish'.to_i
 => 11
```

This is not a vulnerability nor a flaw. If you're worried about input like this, I'd ask for an example where you think it could cause you harm.

Additionally if you'd like to be super defensive, use `Integer(`

```
2.2.1 :004 > Integer('11~gibberish')
  ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "11~gibberish"
2.2.1 :005 > Integer('11')
  => 11
```

Comment: Ah! I get it now. So Ruby handles the type correction before the request is made. I did not face any harm but it did not appear appropriate. Is it a good practice to be super defensive the way you have described it?

Comment: If you'd like to be defensive you can. The `to_i` method will never let anything but integers through, so SQL injection is not something you need to worry about. The only thing to be defensive about is not exposing `Users` that you shouldn't be. For that, I'd recommend an authorization library like `cancancan` or something similar.